# What Morrey and Campanato space characterize

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

[Morrey and Campanato space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrey%E2%80%93Campanato_space) is some subspace of $L^p$. We know that for a bounded domain $\Omega$, $L^p$ space characterize how the function blow up at some point. I want to know what Morrey and Campanato space characterize?

---

For bounded domain $\Omega$ and fixed $p$, if $\lambda<\mu$, we have $$L^{p,\mu}\subset L^{p,\lambda}$$
for Morrey space ,then since $L^{p,n}\cong L^{\infty}$, so it seems that Morrey space is another way to characterize blow-up. 
It is a bit different for Campanato space when $\lambda\geq n$, for $\mathcal{L}^{p,\mu}\cong C^{0,\alpha}$. Thus it seems it characterize kind of oscillation.

Comment: Could you please explain why "for a bounded domain $\Omega$, $L^p$ space characterize how the function blow up at some point"? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [lecture notes](https://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?id=ve_mfs_sem_vor0&key1=0&key2=371&key3=1053&L=1) by Melanie Rupflin answer the question *"What is a Morrey Space? What is a Campanato Space?"*

The **Morrey space** $L^{p,\lambda}$ is a subset of $L^p$ containing functions $f$ on a domain $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that the integral of $|f|^p$ over a ball $B$ of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ goes to zero at least as fast as $r^\lambda$ uniformly in $x_0$.

The purpose of the restriction of $L^p$ to the subspace $L^{p,\lambda}$ is that it allows for an alternative to the Sobolev-Embedding Theorem which can be used with exponent $p$ adapted to the equation (and not, for example, fixed by dimensionality). Choosing a smaller $p$ results in having to show a Morrey-Property with larger $\lambda$.

The **Campanato space** ${\cal L}^{p,\lambda}$ is defined similarly as the corresponding Morrey space, but the integral of $|f|^p$ is replaced by the integral of $|f-\bar{f}|^p$, where $\bar{f}$ is the average of $f$ over the ball. This is less restrictive, so $L^{p,\lambda}\subset {\cal L}^{p,\lambda}$. The less restrictive definition of Campanato spaces allows for an integral characterization of Hölder continuity: $C^{0,\alpha}={\cal L}^{p,m+p\alpha}$.

Of particular interest is the case $\lambda=m$ where $\lambda$ equals the dimensionality of the domain $\Omega$. Then ${\cal L}^{p,m}={\cal L}^{1,m}$ characterizes functions of bounded mean oscillations, meaning bounded $|B|^{-1}\int_B|f(x)-\bar{f}|dx$. It lies in between $\cap_{p>1}L^p$ and $L^\infty$.

A simple example of a function in ${\cal L}^{1,1}$ is $\log x$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: It seems that the link doesn't work

Comment: I think I have fixed the link; somehow that site registers an unique ID for each download of the lecture notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am thinking the embedding $L^{p,\lambda}\subset L^{q,\mu}$ as long as $\frac{n-p}{\lambda}\leq \frac{n-q}{\mu}$ and $p>q$. Since we are considering the blow up of the function at the point compared with $r^{\lambda}$. why we need the condition $p>q$, because I think $\frac{n-p}{\lambda}\leq \frac{n-q}{\mu}$ is enough.

Comment: are you sure of this embedding relation? theorem 0.0.12 (4) in [these notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f12/MorreyCampanato.pdf) has a different inequality with a proof.

Comment: Would you mind me asking something not quite relevant to this question? By "a domain $\Omega$", do you mean a connected open set or just an open set? I have seen various usage of the term "domain" in PDE, and it in some cases refers to a connected open set, whereas in other cases refers to an open set, and it is usually the case that the authors are reluctant to explain in advance what they exactly mean by using this term. Similar ambiguity or even (to some extent) abusage seems not rare in PDE. How to you think we should deal with this situation? Thank you.